# How to apply Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to JSON file on PHP server

Tags: php, json, http-headers

I'm trying to make a JSON file on my PHP web server have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. I have a temporary solution, which is to have a PHP file which essentially spits out the JSON data

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('data.json');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Only, I'd really rather not do this because it's kinda ugly. Is it possible for the raw JSON file to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set such that any source can use XHR to get it? Or do I have to keep using my ugly PHP solution?

Comment: As I know Jason could only contains objects.I had to face same problem, an the solution only keep this.But if you follow good reuse of codes , you can keep this in a single file.

Comment: @MohamedNizar That's a shame. I guess the best I can do is something like 'my.website/json/?v=data' and have a file index.php at root/json/ such that it simply reads the above request as a request for root/json/data.json and spits it out with the appropriate headers. CORS sucks.